# How to kill word document from taskbar using powershell script

Tags: powershell, office-automation

I am writing a script to close word document from taskbar using `PowerShell` script. I am able to unpin the document using:

```
Pin-Taskbar -Item  -Action <Pin|Unpin>
```

However I need to close the document not unpin it. Not sure how to find the specific document and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following will close all the Word documents within all the Word applications, asking them if they want to save the document before it is closed. Then all Word application processes are killed off.

```
$wd = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$wd.Documents | % { $_.Close() }
Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "WINWORD"} | Stop-Process
```

Comment: Thanks. this is working fine but I need the document to ask the user to give pop-up for saving. Force closing the document without saving would mean losing the data.

Comment: @user3190414 I have updated my answer so was users are asked to save there work before it is closed.

Comment: Thank you Richard. This is working. I tried this for excel and powerpoint as well but it always gives error. Following is what I have tried: 
For Excel: $wd = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') 
   $wd.Workbooks | % { $_.Close() }.
   Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "EXCEL"} | Stop-Process

.          For Powerpoint:
$wd = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Powerpoint.Application')
   $wd.Presentations | % { $_.Close() }
   Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "POWERPOINT"} | Stop-Process

Comment: @user3190414 Can you create another question with the error and the code you are using?

Comment: Error code is                                                                                $excel.ActiveWorkbook | % { $_.Close() }
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound